# Spring Security: explicit credentials doesnt log me in, says bad credentials

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

This is my Spring Security config class

```
@EnableWebSecurity 
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
 
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
 
     @Override
     protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
         auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                 .withUser("john.doe")
                 .password(passwordEncoder().encode("secret"))
                 .roles("USER");
     }
 
     @Bean
     public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
         return passwordEncoder;
     } 
}
```

This is the login page

[image]

When I login using "john.doe" and "secret" as specified in the source code, it returns "BAD CREDENTIALS".  What is the reason?

Comment: and when enabling your debug logs for spring security it says?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that @Configuration is not added and @Bean is not injected into the Spring container

Answer (score 1):

You don't use the encoding correctly. You basically set the encoded word `secret` as the password which is usually something like `$2a$12$.....` depending on the currently used salt. Pass the password directly:

```
auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
    .withUser("john.doe")
    .password("secret")
    .roles("USER");
```